# 500 Error when calling an API in C# with having ID in URL

Tags: c#, api

I need to Call a API using C# to this URL: I changed the URL so not working here but it is working in postman)

https://uattest.com/api/leads/28/comments

This is the object to post:

```
{ 
     "code":"22535345454-263663", 
     "text":"This is a test"
}
```

This is working fine when I post via postman, but when I post using my C# code I am getting 500 error. This is my C# code:

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("AddNote")]
    public Task<NoteReturnModel> AddNote(int LeadId, Comments note)
    {
        return Repository.AddNote(LeadId, note);
    }
```

**Repository**

```
   public async Task<NoteReturnModel> AddNote(int LeadId, Comments note)
    {
        using (GetWSObject<NoteReturnModel> addObjectInt = new GetWSObject<NoteReturnModel>())
        {
            string URL = string.Format("/api/leads/" + LeadId+ "/comments");
            return await addObjectInt.PostWSObjectModel(URL, note);
        }
    }
```

**and this is PostWSObjectModel Method:**

```
  public async Task<T> PostWSObjectModel(string uriActionString, Object model)
       {
        T returnValue = default(T);

        try
        {
              using (var client = new HttpClient())
               {
                   client.BaseAddress = new Uri(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"]);
                   var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uriActionString, content);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                returnValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(((HttpResponseMessage)response).Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            }

            return returnValue;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw (e);
        }
    }
```

I am checking all the URLs are correct, in this line that calling   HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uriActionString, content); giving error.

Comment: The default headers in the c# request are not the same as postman.  Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the 1st request in the postman connection with the 1st request in the c# connection.  Then make the c# request look exactly like the postman request.

Comment: A 500 error is application-specific so there is little that can be said about it without more information. Perhaps you could try capturing the HTTP traffic and checking for any differences.

Comment: hi nik, just an advice based on experience testing an API, do it using something a bit raw, like curl. it will allow you to control headers totally by yourself (postman wont add things) and force you to do some menial work such as url encoding, so you can see the actual thing it accept and it didnt. my colleague kept testing his api using postman, but it broke down when i throw things using curl. turns out the previous developer filters incoming request based on [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) header for "spam protection".

Comment: BTW Don't use `.Result` because that will block your thread and makes any `async` anything but asynchronous. It would be better to do something like: `var responseString = await ((HttpResponseMessage)response).Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` then `returnValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);`

Comment: @Barns Thank you, I will do that just as I ma getting error right is call and even before Serialize response. I wonder if the way I send model is right as I always send object never had value in between URL how this has LeadId in URL.